# View a pdf with pdf.js but disable direct access to the PDF (prevent download)

Tags: .htaccess, pdf, view, download, pdf.js

I'm very according with PDF.JS but now I need some help. 
I load (view) the pdf file online with PDF.JS but I need that don't be downloaded. I managed to remove the download button/function from HTML but now I need to know how to prevent direct access to the (without impeding PDF.JS to read it).
Any ideas? :) Thanks

Comment: It's out of scope of pdf.js "hide" the content from the transmission. PDFJS.getDocument can accept Uint8Array, so encrypt it as you want. However it will not be a secret though, just to prevent from blindly downloading the file. As alternative, the same effect can be reached by placing a random password on each PDF file -- again just inconvience since any web developer can peek into the JS source code and extract this password.

Answer (score 3):

You can block direct access to the file by .htaccess:

```
# Block direct access to PDF
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.pdf$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER}  !YOURDOMAIN\.COM [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://YOURDOMAIN.COM/forbidden
```

You need also to prevent caching of pdf files

Answer (score 0):

You can't. You can download any content that goes through the browser, with the appropriate tool, even if you use javascript to load it. For example the "DownloadHelper" addon for Firefox will capture anything from youtube videos to simple images that the script downloads dynamically.

The only way to prevent it is to use 3rd party addons that can download content without the browser. Adobe Flash's RTMP protocol is one example. It circumvents the browser so it's invisible for the other addons.

But I don't suppose you'd want to write a PDF viewer in flash just so no one could download it.

Comment: Spin on your idea: use WebRTC or WebSockets to transmit PDF content. You don't need to transmit the entire file -- PDF.js can request PDF document ranges.

Comment: I'm not familiar with how that works, and even that is only obfuscation, but I agree that it's unlikely that users would be willing to spend time reassembling the PDF from it's pages.